# How do I listen for a Project Change event from an MS Project VSTO Add-in?

Tags: vsto, ms-project

My Add-in has an application event ProjectBeforeTaskChange that is available from the ThisAddIn class. What I need is a ProjectAfterTaskChange event, but that doesn't exist. Is there a way to listen for the Project Change event from an application level add-in?

My end goal is to set three number fields when a specific text field changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ProjectBeforeTaskChange` is the correct event to use to monitor field changes. The word "Before" refers to the fact that the handler can prevent the change by setting the Cancel argument to True. The event is triggered when the user makes a change to a task field.

Here's a vb.net example that increments the Number1 and Number2 fields whenever the Text1 field changes:

```
Private Sub Application_ProjectBeforeTaskChange(tsk As MSProject.Task, Field As MSProject.PjField, NewVal As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles Application.ProjectBeforeTaskChange

    If Field = MSProject.PjField.pjTaskText1 Then
        Select Case NewVal
            Case Is = "In-work": tsk.Number1 = 50
            Case Is = "Complete": tsk.Number1 = 100
            Case Else: tsk.Number1 = 0
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Here's the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/application-projectbeforetaskchange-event-project) page.

Here's a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671970/microsoft-project-vsto-c-sharp-event-listener-when-changed) showing the c# framework.

Comment: The problem is that the event triggers prior to the change taking effect. I need to change field 2 based on the result of the change in field 1. So, if field 1 is a custom list and I choose element B, then field 2 should change to 5. But if I choose element C, then it should change to 7. With ProjectBeforeTaskChange, the field 2 value changes based on what the field 1 value was BEFORE the change.

Comment: The NewVal argument contains the new value. Use that instead of the task field value.

Comment: ...doh! It just didn't click when I was reading the documentation. Thanks so much!!!